# buildTransaction for swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Tags: web3js, nodejs, cpp-ethereum

I'm a beginner with Web3 programming. Trying to understand how all it all works.

Managed to get some *nodejs* code working for buying tokens but when trying to create a script that sells tokens I get an error message related to the .buildTransaction method.
I don't understand where I can get the buildTransaction method from?
I guess it should go into the ABI same as for the swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens but I have looked everywhere and can't even find an example so it seems like I'm missing something.

Would really appreciate some help on this. Have been sitting 3 hours just trying to understand how I can get the buildTransaction to work.

My code:

```
exchange_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    500000000, 0,
    [spending_this_token,buying_this_token],
    your_wallet_address,
    deadline
).buildTransaction({
    'from': your_wallet_address,
    'gasPrice': Web3Client.utils.toWei('20','gwei'),
    'gasLimit': estimate,
    'nonce': nonce,
})
```

Error message:

> TypeError:
> contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(...).buildTransaction
> is not a function

Comment: Welcome, what is the library you're using, in which programming language ?

Comment: Thank you.
I am using NodeJS, including all these libraries per below:

`
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var Web3 = require('web3')
var Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
const ethers = require("ethers");
const web3utils = require("web3-utils");
`

Comment: Alright, looks like you're using the web3.py syntax. Please refer to the web3.js library instead.

This is what you wanna use to send a transaction: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send
And to add an account to sign the transaction: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#web3-eth-accounts